# What good system administrator podcasts are out there?

Tags: podcast

The similar question on Stack Overflow, 
*[What good technology podcasts are out there?](http://stackoverflow.mobi/question1644_What-good-technology-podcasts-are-out-there-.aspx)*, has lots of answers focused on software development.

What podcasts do you listen to for learning about the following?

- Information technology trends
- Network administration techniques
- Security issues and threats
- Other system/network administration issues.

---

Summary:

- [RunAs Radio](http://feeds.feedburner.com/RunasRadio)
- [Security Now!](http://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm)
- [Crypto-Gram Security Podcast](http://crypto-gram.libsyn.com/)
- [Hak5](http://www.hak5.org/)
- [VMWare VMTN](http://blogs.vmware.com/vmtn/podcasts/index.html)
- [Windows Weekly](http://twit.tv/ww)
- [PaulDotCom Security](http://pauldotcom.com/)
- [FeatherCast](http://feathercast.org/)
- [Packet Pushers Podcast](http://packetpushers.net/)
- [Floss Weekly](http://twit.tv/FLOSS)
- [Mind of Root](http://www.mindofroot.com/)
- [Radio Free Security](http://www.watchguard.com/education/radiofreesecurity.asp)
- [IT Idiots](http://www.itidiots.com/)
- [TechNet Edge](http://edge.technet.com/)
- [Network Security Podcast](http://mckeay.libsyn.com/)
- [Webpulp.tv](http://webpulp.tv/)

Answer (score 18):

#### [RunAs Radio](http://www.runasradio.com/)

Answer (score 13):

I regularly listen too and enjoy

- [Security Now](http://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm)
- [Floss Weekly](http://twit.tv/FLOSS)
- [Security Bites](http://news.cnet.com/security-bites-podcast/)

Comment: +1 for Security Now.  Laporte is fine, but Gibson is a God!

Comment: Are Sthe ecurity Bites still released? Your link seems to point at old releases?

Comment: Please, the next time just post one podcast per answer. :)

Comment: Isn't Gibson the dope who claimed XP was going to crash the interweb?

Answer (score 8):

[PaulDotCom Security Weekly](http://pauldotcom.com) is a weekly podcast hosted by a group of network penetration testers and SANS instructors that covers some of the tactics and tools that attackers use as well as news and information for how sysadmins can protect their systems.

[Mind of Root](http://www.mindofroot.com/) is a weekly podcast that covers more of the general sysadmin topics.

[Radio Free Security](http://www.watchguard.com/education/radiofreesecurity.asp) is a monthly podcast from WatchGuard (they make security appliances).  They have a lot of good insight on security and protecting your network.

Answer (score 7):

The **Stack Overflow** podcast :)

Comment: Thats more of that which craft called programming isn't it :)

Comment: They talk quite a bit about running the stackoverflow.com site. Server configurations, load, uptime, etc. RAID is one of the podcast bingo words... :)

Comment: witch. :)

hmm15charshuh?

Comment: RAID may be one of the bingo words but both speakers almost always gets it completely wrong though ;p

Answer (score 4):

On the Linux side, checkout these podcasts from [JupiterBroadcasting](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/):

- [Linux Action Show](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/?cat=4): about new Linux stuff, interviews (Mark Shuttleworth, CrossOver's CEO, Linspire's CEO, etc.) and more
- [In Depth Look](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/?cat=153): in depth on a specific topic, like [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) or security tools
- [The Big Story & News Update](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/?cat=154): short podcast about news in the Linux world

Answer (score 4):

For you Windows folks out there:

*[IT Idiots](http://www.itidiots.com/)*

They don't do much system administration type podcasts anymore, but there is a fairly extensive archive with good Windows video podcasts.

Answer (score 3):

**[Buzz Out Loud](http://bol.cnet.com)**

It is not exactly system administrator material, but it gives a good overview about what's going on in the world of technology.

Comment: I listen to Buzz Out Loud, but I find much of their news to be consumerism gossip tech news, and less cutting edge IT news.

Answer (score 3):

The [PodNutz podcast](http://www.podnutz.com/podnutz).

Funny name, but handy Podcast for small businesses and individials involved with technical support/repair (34 shows to date).

Steve, the host, runs a computer repair business and actually listens to what his guests are saying and then asks relevant follow-up  questions.

Answer (score 3):

Some more:

- [TechNet Edge](http://edge.technet.com/)
- [Network Security Podcast](http://mckeay.libsyn.com/)
- [The Silver Bullet Security Podcast](http://www.cigital.com/silverbullet/)
- [Going Deep](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/) (though not just a SecAdmin show)

Answer (score 3):

**[This Week in Tech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Week_in_Tech)**

Comment: This week in Tech isn't really very sysadmin-y

Answer (score 3):

It's self promotion, so sorry about that, but I thought I'd let you know about the podcast that Brandon Burton and I just launched, called SysAdministrivia

http://www.sysadministrivia.com

It'll be on iTunes shortly, but until it is, please download it and check it out!

Answer (score 2):

Healthcare IT Podcast - http://itpodcast.org/blog/

> http://itpodcast.org/blog/about/ -
>   This site was started on January 2nd,
>   2008 with the intention to house a
>   blog and post podcasts I intend to
>   produce surrounding healthcare IT and
>   the issues we are working through in
>   this business. I hope that others will
>   find this useful, and that this will
>   become a resource others in our
>   industry will use.

Answer (score 2):

[Hak5](http://www.hak5.org/) bills itself as a TV show about hacking. They cover a lot of weird stuff like installing linux on gameboys, but at the end of the day they do a lot of hands-on tutorials with networking software and server hardware. The sysadmin-relevant parts of the show are a bit Windows heavy sometimes but they also have lots of Linux coverage and use it often in their projects.

Answer (score 2):

DevOpsCafe - http://devopscafe.org/

Focused on DevOps movement and (agile) sysadmin stuff. They use to record video interviews too. Recommended.

Answer (score 1):

It is more security related, but *[Risky Business](http://risky.biz)* is very good.

Answer (score 0):

Tech Snap from Jupiter Broadcasting is great.

A lot of current security and IT news along with overviews of system and network setups/solutions.

http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/?s=tech+snap&x=0&y=0

Answer (score 0):

Since no-one else has mentioned it: [linux outlaws](http://linuxoutlaws.com) It's more of a light hearted podcast (think lug radio, but new, improved, and even better) but there's surprisingly good content in the shows.