# What are the top 10 best podcasts for sys admins?

Tags: podcast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What good Sysadmin podcasts are out there?](https://serverfault.com/questions/3765/what-good-sysadmin-podcasts-are-out-there)

I know there are a ton of podcasts out there, but what are the best ones for sys admins?

Comment: very similar question : http://serverfault.com/questions/3765/what-good-sysadmin-podcasts-are-out-there

Answer (score -1):

http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/Help-Desk/ is a helpdesk show with questions about Microsoft products. Not directly server related but pretty interesting.